# How to extract zip code values from react-geosuggest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

## Short description

I am trying to capture the City, State, & Zipcode value from the results provided by the `onSuggestSelect` prop using the `npm react-geosuggest` component. You can find info about it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geosuggest

## Expected results

I created a handler to process the changes returned by `onSuggestSelect` and in that handler I am trying to capture the data I need to persist it into state. Using the following:

```
handleOnSuggestSelect(suggestion) {
  this.setState({
    address: suggestion.label
  });
}
```

I expected that the suggestion.label value would store the entire address as such:
`1234 Maple Street, Miami, FL, 33010, USA`

## Actual results

Instead of `1234 Maple Street, Miami, FL, 33010, USA`, what I saw was that a value of: `1234 Maple Street, Street` showed up instead. Why does the value of `,Street` show up after the initial street address instead of the rest of the expected info (city, state, zip)?

## Additional Information

How do I get the different address components from the label? Especially the city, state, and zip code?

You can see how I have the `react-geosuggest` component set up as described in the answer I posted here: [Get input value of react-geosuggest input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235691/get-input-value-of-react-geosuggest-input-field/54045181#54045181)

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual address components in you `handleOnSuggestSelect` you can access them like so:

```js
handleOnSuggestSelect(suggest) {
  if (!suggest.gmaps) {
    return;
  }

  const components = suggest.gmaps.address_components;

  const address = {
    street: this.findAddressComponent(components, 'street_number', 'short_name') + ' ' + this.findAddressComponent(components, 'route', 'short_name'),
    city: this.findAddressComponent(components, 'locality', 'short_name'),
    state: this.findAddressComponent(components, 'administrative_area_level_1', 'short_name'),
    zip: this.findAddressComponent(components, 'postal_code', 'short_name'),
  }

  this.setState({
    address
  });
}

findAddressComponent(components, type, version) {
  const address = components.find(function(component) {
    return (component.types.indexOf(type) !== -1);
  });

  return address[version];
}
```

Rather than trying to get the address components from the label try the above.